# Ошибка при инжекте DLL-файла

Tags: c++, dll, память

Возникла ошибка, при инжекте собственного DLL-файла в игру.

```
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x542B101C (RMP-GUI.dll) в gta_sa.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000.
```

Если открыть отладку при помощи Microsoft Visual Studio 15, то жалуется на данную строку.

```
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* oEndScene)(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice);
oEndScene pEndScene = NULL;
HRESULT APIENTRY myEndScene(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
   if (!Render.pFont)
       Render.pFont->OnLostDevice();
   else
   {

    Render.TextDraw(40, 40, GREEN, "Test", Left_Text);

    Render.pFont->OnLostDevice();
    Render.pFont->OnResetDevice();
    }
    return pEndScene(pDevice);
 }
```